# Elasticsearch indices

Tags: akeneo

Could someone please shed some light on the necessity of three ES indices in Akeneo PIM. In particular, i'd like to know whats the difference between these two:

- `akeneo_pim_product`
- `akeneo_pim_product_and_product_model`

Because to me they seem very similar, but I can't seem to be able to perform a search by parent in `akeneo_pim_product`, the results for the search only appear in `akeneo_pim_product_and_product_model`. This seems awkward and in order to make the parent filter to work in product search, I needed to change the index on which it is being performed. Everything seems to work fine, but i'm still not sure if I haven't messed anything up by doing this, because I simply can't seem to find any info on the differences between them.

Any info on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot search on the `parent` field in the `akeneo_pim_product` index because it is only present in the `akeneo_pim_product_and_product_model`.

We had a related bug fixed very recently with the same reason: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/pull/8344

We are thinking about adding the `parent` field in the products index, but we don't want to do it in a patch version.

Best regards,
JM

Comment: Note that in the future, **we may only keep one index**, as they will become the same.

Comment: I see that. But, can you please tell me the difference between these two indices, also, what negative effects may I expect if I direct all my searches to `akeneo_pim_product_and_product_model` in stead of `akeneo_pim_product`